# Access subform object hangs when selecting column?

Tags: performance, ms-access, query-optimization

I have an Access app I wrote, to handle the data work a team needs to do, rather than working on a giant excel spreadsheet.  The one annoying constraint is people are sharing this db over a wifi connection.

I have the db split, so users get a copy of the front end in runtime, when they run a bat file shortcut. The backend is on a hard drive, connected to a laptop, which is directly connected to the wifi router.

In this app, I have a form with a combo and some buttons to perform functions on dynamic queries, so the user can filter the records.  Everything is in 1 table, and the table has about 75,000 records.  When the users go to the form, on load, a sql string is constructed, to set the base recordsource for the form.

When a user clicks any column in the datasheet view subform object, the whole form freezes and you can see in the bottom right Access says "running query".  The users like to click the drop down arrow by the column to filter based on values, and that usually isn't too bad, but clicking on the column seems to trigger a query to run and I don't know why. Can anyone help?

I just want to up the performance on this application as much as possible.  These forms allow the users to filter to a set, select the rows they want, click a button, and a column gets tagged (assigning those records to someone).  Then a button shows, they click it, and those results are exported to an excel formatted template. They send that to the person assigned the records. Later that comes back to us, and I have a button for our users to import that sheet and process what the assigned person entered on their records.

Thanks for any help anyone can give!

Comment: If when you say 'When a user clicks any column' you mean the title of the column, what is happening is the data is being sorted by that column. This can be a taxing process as the entire query is run once more with an ORDER BY clause, and if the column isn't indexed, it will be slow. I don't think there is a way of stopping this 'sort when a column name is clicked' function in an Access datasheet view.

Comment: What is backend DB? Access table and linked to frontend? For network sharing with large dataset `MS-SQL` is best for backend database. Just clicking to column name shouldn't run any query nor sorting/filtering unless you click on sort/filter. It will only select full column. I am not sure but you can try to set `Allow Layout View` property to `No`.

Comment: Thanks to you both. They are really clicking the arrow at the column title, so they can filter, but it's hanging before it even presents the menu for the filters. So it hasn't sorted or filtered anything. Just clicking it, causes the "running query" to happen.  The back end is Access. Our project is too small for us to get SQL. I wish we could.

Comment: It's possible that the backend table is being queried to determine the options for the filter menu, given these are dynamic depending on the columns/data in the table. This is almost certainly a combination of factors causing this performance issue. While this isn't an easy prospect, especially given the likely large size of the DB in question, refactoring using 3rd normal form should increase performance even in Access over a WiFi connection, but this would require a lot of work.

Comment: MS SQLServer Express is free. I just installed it on my laptop last week. It was a challenge but once I got it in place, connecting Access to it was simpler than expected. MySQL is another freebie option.

Comment: However, don't know if any other platform backend will perform any better over wifi.

Comment: A shared Access backend over Wi-Fi is a definite no-go. Try with a wired connection for both machines. Also, check how your query runs when opened directly (not via the form).

Comment: Thanks. I was looking at this last night.  I construct the dynamic sql, set that as the sql for the saved query I have, and then I set the subform sourceobject to be that query.  So it is really a saved query that they are clicking on.  

I thought about normalizing the table, but it will cause too many issues for the users who need to be able to just work with datasheet view, and have it be updateable.  As for SQL express or mysql, I'm wondering if the laptop its on could take it. Would that really help? Where is a free install? I thought it went cloud.

Comment: A fast and stable WiFi shouldn't perform much worse than a wired connection. As Will wrote, the problem is that Access hat to analyze the full column to define the filter options. To avoid that, you could build your own filter methods with VBA. -- Sql Server Express ([link](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sql-server/sql-server-downloads)) could help, but if your query is very complex it might still be slow with 75k records.

Comment: I am thinking the same thing, Andre. I set up filter drop downs on the main unbound form, to test that out and see if that makes filtering way quicker. It means more coding on my part to manage them applying filters, removing them, tagging results, and exporting results to specific specs, but It may be worth the savings I get in the performance.

Comment: So I installed SQL express, set up a database in SSMS, and now when I try to link the table, I get a SQLState: '0100' SQL Server Error: 53 SQL Server Does not exist or access denied.  I did some research, and based on what I found, I set up a SQL account in SSMS, giving it read/write rights to the database.  I don't understand why it won't link the table in Access.  Do I need to post this as a new question?

Comment: Nevermind, I figured it out. I needed to put the server\instance name to connect.  Wow! It worked! I'm setting it up on the shared laptop, and then I can see if this improves performance. I'm also moving filters to the main unbound form, and I found if you select a column on the subform, when it starts running the query unnecessarily, just hit esc and it will stop running it and give you the filter drop down.

Comment: This is the problem: "When the users go to the form, on load, a sql string is constructed, to set the base recordsource for the form." If that means you're loading the entire table, DO NOT do that. Leave the form empty until a request is made and make sure your queries/filters/etc return the fewest num of records necessary. You don't need to deal with another db.

Comment: Thank you, wazz. I ended up taking harun24hr’s recommendation and migrating the backend to sql express. It took a bit to get the remote I’d call connection protocol working, but now it is so much faster and so much better. Access is horrible with presenting data and managing query requests. SQL does all of that so much better, it’s not even close.

Comment: Harun24HR, if you want to post the moving the SQL as an answer, I will accept it, as it is the solution I went with and it is working excellently.